# how to add anchor to django url in template

Tags: django, django-templates, anchor, django-urls

I am trying to add an anchor to my url in a django template like this:

```
<a data-hover="Are You At Risk?" href="{% url 'home' %}#container">My link</a>
```

This does not work.

How can I get this to move to the anchor point when this link is clicked?

Comment: Maybe the [django-urltags](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-urltags/0.1) module can help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Make sure the actual anchor is defined like this in your template:

```
<a name="container"></a>
```

And then link to it the way you did:

```
<a data-hover="Are You At Risk?" href="{% url 'home' %}#container">My link</a>
```

If this does not work add `/` just before your `#`-tag:

```
<a data-hover="Are You At Risk?" href="{% url 'home' %}/#container">My link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

past it between your anchor tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'your_url_name' object.parameter %}" class="pull-right" > Anchor Text{{object.parameter}}</a>
```