# Django: Return to the same point in last HTML

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'm trying to implement a back button on Django template that once you click on it, you return to the last HTML BUT also to the same point in it (let's say that if you scroll down the page and moved to another one. So when you click back you want to get to the same point and not to the top of the page). 
Is there any way to do so in Django template without using Ajax?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an html anchor tag. See this question:

[how to add anchor to django url in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940811/how-to-add-anchor-to-django-url-in-template)

Comment: I didn't quite understand how it would help... can you explain a little more?