# How to add link to a certain section in the rendered page in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I render a page with additional key parameter added to the URL. For example:

```
<form action="{% url 'Page' %}">
    <select name="order">
       <option value='up'> Up</option>
       <option value='down'> Down</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the views.py file, I render the template file based on the key parameter appears in the request path_info.

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Every time I render this template, the page always starts from the top, however, I want the rendered page to go to a certain section of the template file, like when you do  tag in HTML to link between sections.

```
<a href="#section">Link</a>
```

It is possible for me to add different links to different section based on the key parameters in the URL (Like "/page/?order=up" go to id="up" and "/page/?order=down" go to id="down") so that the rendered page doesn't always start at the top?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't mention which method you had tried, I'll suggest you go look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940811/how-to-add-anchor-to-django-url-in-template).

```html
<!-- something like -->
<a href="{% url 'page' %}/#section">My link</a>
```

Comment: I think this can answer my question. Thank you!